# VMWare player вернуть место

Tags: mysql, vmware

`VMware® Workstation 12 Player` на `Windows 7`
Версия `12.1.1 build-3770994`
В качестве гостя - `Red Hat 4.4.7-3.`
На днях по ошибке в `mysql` выполнил запрос `create table ad select` c кривым условием из-за чего на диске съелось 4 гигабайта места.
Табличка в итоге не создалась.
Если выключить `VMWare player` - 4 гига в систему возвращаются.
После включения съедаются обратно.
Как заставить гостя вернуть место?
Гость старый и очень ценный - на нём необходимо отлаживать некоторые вещи...

Comment: а снапшоты или полностью бэкапы машины не делали??

Comment: Не делали, эта версия плеера либо не имеет такой опции, либо я не знаю где она.

Comment: там когда выбираешьмашинку, на панеле вверху есть иконка с часиками там и лежат управления снапшотами.

Comment: ну попробуйте поменять тип диска.

Answer (score 2):

Никак, потому что ты при создании выбрал динамически расширяющийся HDD.
Попробуй конечно посмотреть есть ли Snapshot (Контрольные точки восстановления)

Comment: Я машинку не создавал, а скачал с cloudera. Может плеер другой попробовать?

Comment: Предлагаю тебе установить полноценную Vmware Pro (Последней версии) и научиться пользоваться SnapShot.
Просто в основной версии есть больше надстроек, например как изменение размера диска.